# Construct tensor with complicated symmetries

Tags: tensors

I have a tensor with following symmetries

```
Clear[G]
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := G[3 - i, 3 - j, 3 - k, 3 - l]
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := G[j, i, l, k]
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := Conjugate[G[k, l, i, j]]
```

where $i,\,j,\,k,\,l\in\{1,\,2\}$. It is fully specified by

```
G[1, 1, 1, 1] = r[1];
G[1, 1, 2, 2] = r[2];
G[1, 2, 1, 2] = r[3];
G[1, 2, 2, 1] = r[4];
G[1, 1, 1, 2] = z;
```

where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I would like to specify the whole tensor by writing

```
Array[G, {2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

This is obviously not possible due to infinite recursion. One can type all the elements manually. But is there an automatic way? Relation 2 can be specified with the help of `SymmetrizedArray`, but I do not know how to specify 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of recursion happens because the order of evaluation in Mathematica is inherently depth-first. Below is my *very very hacky* solution – some sort of a random-walk evaluation order. Obviously, one could (and someone surely did it already) write a proper breadth-first evaluation, but I think this random walk will do just fine for small enough tensors.

```
Clear[G];

ind = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, 
       {1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}};

r /: Conjugate[r[a_]] = r[a];
G[1, 1, 1, 1] = r[1];
G[1, 1, 2, 2] = r[2];
G[1, 2, 1, 2] = r[3];
G[1, 2, 2, 1] = r[4];
G[1, 1, 1, 2] = z;

G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := G[3 - i, 3 - j, 3 - k, 3 - l] /; {j, i, l, k} \[Element] ind
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := G[j, i, l, k] /; {j, i, l, k} \[Element] ind
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := Conjugate[G[k, l, i, j]] /; {k, l, i, j} \[Element] ind

G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := ReleaseHold@RandomChoice[{
    Hold@G[3 - i, 3 - j, 3 - k, 3 - l],
    Hold@G[j, i, l, k],
    Hold@Conjugate[G[k, l, i, j]]
    }]

Array[G, {2, 2, 2, 2}] // Refine[#, r[_] \[Element] Reals] &

(* {{{{r[1], z}, {z, r[2]}}, {{Conjugate[z], r[3]}, {r[4], 
    Conjugate[z]}}}, {{{Conjugate[z], r[4]}, {r[3], 
    Conjugate[z]}}, {{r[2], z}, {z, r[1]}}}} *)
```

Comment: Nice, however, `r[2]` is real and in the final result there should not appear `Conjugate[r[2]]`.

Comment: @yarchik, oh, right, I fixed it.

Comment: This is one possibility. However, I believe that the final result could be obtained without invoking the assumption of being real, by means of the two first rules. This brings me to the point: rule with `Conjugate` should only be used when two others bring no simplification.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of ordering your definitions appropriately.  Start by defining the simple symmetries:

```
Clear[G];
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] /; ! OrderedQ[{{i, j, k, l}, {j, i, l, k}}] := G[j, i, l, k];
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] /; ! OrderedQ[{{i, j, k, l}, {k, l, i, j}}] := Conjugate[G[k, l, i, j]];
```

Here are your (minimal) specification of the elements:

```
G[1, 1, 1, 1] = r[1];
G[1, 1, 2, 2] = r[2];
G[1, 2, 1, 2] = r[3];
G[1, 2, 2, 1] = r[4];
G[1, 1, 1, 2] = z;
```

Finally, for the cases that do not match, subtract all indices from 3:

```
G[i_, j_, k_, l_] := G[3 - i, 3 - j, 3 - k, 3 - l]
```

With these definitions in that order, you get what you are looking for:

```
Array[G, {2, 2, 2, 2}]
(*
  {{{{r[1], z}, {z, r[2]}}, 
    {{Conjugate[z], r[3]}, {r[4], Conjugate[z]}}},
   {{{Conjugate[z], r[4]}, {r[3], Conjugate[z]}},
    {{Conjugate[r[2]], z}, {z, r[1]}}}}
*)
```

Comment: Nice, however, `r[2]` is real and in the final result there should not appear `Conjugate[r[2]]`.